# Phantom DNS A Record Netlify

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, netlify

I have exported dns zone in Netlify, and have few records. In testing purposes i added new A record for one of my aws ec2

(example "myapp.thebest.com A 10.10.10.10)

, but later i put my ec2 behind application load balancer and try to add cname or alias record with the same name

(example "myapp.thebest.com ALIAS(OR CNAME) myapplicationloadbalancer.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com

So i expect to forward my traffic throught load balancer, but traffic goes directly to ec2 instance & when cheking dig or nslookup i can found deleted phantom A records that direcrly point to my ec2.
Whats wrong, and how to solve it?

So i expect to forward my traffic throught load balancer, but traffic goes directly to ec2 instance & when cheking dig or nslookup i can found deleted phantom A records that direcrly point to my ec2.
Whats wrong, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some bugs on netlify nameservers, so solution for now is just

1.delete cname (alias) current record,

2.create old phantom dns record:

3.check via dig/nslookup

4.create needed current record a,cname or alias